# How Manage Big Linq DataContext?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, memory-management

The major subject in .net programs is "How manage memory for best performance".
so Microsoft use garbage collector in .net and with that, we don't need to do something for managing memory(or better say we can use GC easily)

But when you develop big project(business app), you make too many tables and database for your own project. so if you use Linq-to-sql, we must build DataContext include hundred or more tables. That make problem for program when you create an object from datacontext, that object give big amount of memory. also we cant divide datacontext to datacontexts(cuz relation between tables)

so "How manage datacontext and memory"?

Comment: On a personal note, I once had about 85 tables in a DataContext, with several 100 GBs of data, running on the Rackspace Cloud. The application worked quite fine

Comment: You say "That make problem for program when you create an object from datacontext, that object give big amount of memory.". Why should that be? Did you run into any particular problem? Are you sure that this problem did not come from something else?

Comment: I don't know that memory management is "The major problem" in .net programming (for some programs it is, but this is an over-generalisation). You seem to be implying that DataContext sucks up huge amounts of memory before it even loads any data. Have you actually measured this?

Comment: thx all
we use own framework developed base on mvp and mvc.

we don't have Rackspace server ;(

also managing your data in business app is major subject. if you don't Attention to that, that make problem for app.

when i run project, after that datacontext object give big amount of memory!

Comment: to jens ♪♪
we have a lot problem about memory management
!) wcf service: for that We try to host wcf in iis
2) Big dataContext
3) garbage don't collecting objects . We try to use gc method and also dispose them handly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Midhat already commented, big databases with hundreds of tables and huge amounts of data  should not be any problem for LINQ to SQL or any O/RM tool what so ever. Perhaps you're doing something wrong. If you're having problems, try posting some code here so we can take a look. Perhaps the problem is that you're caching a single `DataContext`. Yes, this will go wrong. I just answered a similar question here at SO, that might interest you. [Read it while it's hot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813076/field-members-vs-method-variables/2813909#2813909)

Comment: I read your "hot answer" :)  .But for testing those solutions I need time. after that i send post result here. Thanks for help(Mean Hot help)

Answer (score 0):

See this for example - "Linq to SQL DataContext Lifetime Management":
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx This approach makes life simpler.

Comment: I see your article before I post my question
I will read that again.