# How to dispose data context after usage

Tags: asp.net, datacontext, iqueryable

I have a member class that returned IQueryable from a data context

```
    public static IQueryable<TB_Country> GetCountriesQ()
    {
        IQueryable<TB_Country> country;

        Bn_Master_DataDataContext db = new Bn_Master_DataDataContext();

        country = db.TB_Countries
            .OrderBy(o => o.CountryName);

        return country;
    }
```

As you can see I don't delete the data context after usage. Because if I delete it, the code that call this method cannot use the IQueryable (perhaps because of deferred execution?). How to force immediate execution to this method? So I can dispose the data context..

Thank you :D

Comment: Don't forget to flag your favorite answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example given by Codeka is correct, and I would advice writing your code with this when the method is called by the presentation layer. However, disposing `DataContext` classes is a bit tricky, so I like to add something about this.

The domain objects generated by LINQ to SQL (in your case the `TB_Countries` class) often contain a reference to the `DataContext` class. This internal reference is needed for lazy loading. When you access for instance list of referenced objects (say for instance: `TB_Country.States`) LINQ to SQL will query the database for you. This will also happen with lazy loaded columns.

When you dispose the `DataContext`, you prevent it from being used again. Therefore, when you return a set of objects as you've done in your example, it is impossible to call the `States` property on a `TB_Country` instance, because it will throw a `ObjectDisposedException`.

This does not mean that you shouldn't dispose the `DataContext`, because I believe you should. How you should solve this depends a bit on the architecture you choose, but IMO you basically got two options:

Option 1. Supply a `DataContext` to the `GetCountriesQ` method.
You normally want to do this when your method is an internal method in your business layer and it is part of a bigger (business) transaction. When you supply a `DataContext` from the outside, it is created outside of the scope of the method and it shouldn't dispose it. You can dispose it at a higher layer. In that situation your method basically looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TB_Country> GetCountriesQ(
    Bn_Master_DataDataContext db)
{
    return db.TB_Countries.OrderBy(o => o.CountryName);
}
```

Option 2. Don't return any domain objects from the `GetCountriesQ` method.
This solution is useful when the method is a public in your business layer and will be called by the presentation layer. You can wrap the data in a specially crafted object (a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) that contains only data and no hidden references to the `DataContext`. This way you have full control over the communication with the database and you can dispose the `DataContext` as you should. I've written more about his on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785506/linq-to-sql-web-application-best-practices/2786713). In that situation your method basically looks like this:

```
public static CountryDTO[] GetCountriesQ()
{
    using (var db = new Bn_Master_DataDataContext())
    {
        var countries;
            from country in db.TB_Countries
            orderby country.CountryName
            select new CountryDTO()
            {
                Name = country.CountryName,
                States = (
                    from state in country.States
                    order by state.Name
                    select state.Name).ToList();
            };

        return countries.ToArray();
    }
}

public class CountryDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StateDTO> States { get; set; }
}
```

As you will read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785506/linq-to-sql-web-application-best-practices/2786713#2786713) there are some smart things you can do that make using DTOs less painful.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the queryable to a list, like so:

```
public static List<TB_Country> GetCountriesQ()
{
    using(var db = new Bn_Master_DataDataContext())
    {
        return db.TB_Countries
            .OrderBy(o => o.CountryName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 By the way Erwin, the using statement here will take care of disposing the data context (the class implements IDisposable) It releases all resources used by the System.Data.Linq.DataContext.