# What are the best practises to improve the application performace while using LINQ Queries?

Tags: asp.net, linq

Could any one tell me how to improve the application performance while writing LINQ Queries ?Like the optimization techniques.

Comment: 1. Profile, profile, profile; don't take anything for granted or micro-optimize without profiling. 2. Be aware of Big O. 3. To a lesser degree, having a rough idea of how the operators work help. (e.g. streaming vs buffering, examining the generated T-SQL and its execution plan for LINQ to SQL).

Comment: Take a look at stackoverflow thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785506/linq-to-sql-web-application-best-practices

Comment: Linq queries in general or Linq to Sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that:
1) You must fetch only date that you need.
2) Use DataLoadOptions

```
  DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
  options.AssociateWith<Category>(cat=> cat.Products.Where<Product>(prod => prod.IsValid));
  context.LoadOptions = options;
```

it is optimize you sql query.

3) Turn off ObjectTrackingEnabled

```
context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```